# Woocommerce attribute as title

Tags: php, attributes, woocommerce, title, product

I am working on a wordpress site with woocommerce integration.

Now i want to override the title of a item with the value of a custom attribute of the same item (On product-archive-page AND single-product-page).

I am messing around with the functions.php but nothing is working for me.

Any woocommerce/.php expert around here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `the_title` filter along with `in_the_loop` , `is_shop` and `is_product` conditional as shown below. Add the following code your theme's functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'custom_the_title' );

function custom_the_title( $title, $id ) {

    global $product;

    /*
     * We use is_shop and is_product to check if the page is product archive
     * or single product page. in_the_loop conditional is used to check if the loop
     * is currently active, otherwise it will over write the page title as well
     */

    if( ( is_shop() || is_product() ) && in_the_loop() ) {

        $attr = $product->get_attributes();

        // $attr contains the attribute array, apply the logic you need
        // and set $title 

        return $title;

    }

    return $title;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively `woocommerce_product_title` is a filter that will only run on products.

Comment: @helgatheviking, I agree. However based on my findings it doesn't work on product archive and single product pages. It works in the cart and checkout pages.

Comment: Yes indeed it dosent work for me on the pages either, could you give me an advice how to manipulate the filter @helgatheviking ?